# Time to first Byte takes over 3 seconds on home page, Fully load time 14s - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, performance, debugging, pagespeed

The site was working fine until recently, the loading speed has dramatically increase, visitor get Internal 500 from time to time. First i thought it was the recent extension I installed, Marisvit Rewards, but after i disabled the extension, it is still very slow to load. Right now, i'm running out of ideas, below are what i done. Hopefully someone can direct me where to look into. Thank you.

- I am using SiteGround Cloud hosting 3 CPU with 8G RAM, and made sure .htaccess and .phi.ini memory_limit are correct
- I have use magento js and css merging, minify, and bundling to decrease the request from ~300 to ~100.
- I have enabled gzip compression
- I am using CDN from cloudflare
- I have enabled memcached
- I have cloned the exact site to develop.gofanco.com on the same hosting, installed the same extension ( without further js/css optimization & without CDN), even that it runs faster than my live site! very weird..

below is from gtmetrix:
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.gofanco.com/wAMHMWR4 ( live site)
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/develop.gofanco.com/FkZg8iIV ( test site)
[image]

below is output from magento profiler, i'm not exactly sure how to find the cause of the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For more speed-up you need to increase the value of these points, check the YSlow tab of the report :

```
1. Minify JavaScript and CSS
2. Use cookie-free domains
3. Reduce DNS lookups
4. Add Expires headers
```

Change the website mode to `Production` as well.

Comment: i have done 1,4, and put into production mode. 2&3 are mostly from external scripts i'm using i believe. I think the main problem was not these, but came from something else? since it was working faster with the same setup